# Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, random

I'm trying to execute a javascript on my website but I'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

I don't know what I've done wrong. It executed perfectly on just 1 website..

Here's the script code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
var dots = [];
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 125;
var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 125;
var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 125;
var radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;

function Dot(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, radiusValue, rValue, gValue, bValue, aValue) {
    this.x = xCoordinate;
    this.y = yCoordinate;
    this.radius = radiusValue;
    this.r = rValue;
    this.g = gValue;
    this.b = bValue;
    this.a = aValue;
}

function dotFilter(element) {
    return element.y >= 0 && element.a >= 0;
}

function drawDots() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    if (dots.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    dots = dots.filter(dotFilter);
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i = i + 1) {
        dots[i].y = dots[i].y - 12;
        dots[i].a = dots[i].a - .03;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(dots[i].x, dots[i].y, dots[i].radius, 0, 4 * Math.PI, true);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + dots[i].r + "," + dots[i].g + "," + dots[i].b + "," + dots[i].a + ")";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
    }
}
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var mouseX, mouseY;
    if (e.offsetX) {
        mouseX = e.offsetX;
        mouseY = e.offsetY;
    } else if (e.layerX) {
        mouseX = e.layerX;
        mouseY = e.layerY;
    }
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 50;
    g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 50;
    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 50;
    radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    dots.push(new Dot(mouseX - 12, mouseY - 12, radius, r, g, b, 1));
};

function clearScreen() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
}
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
window.setInterval(drawDots, 70);
```

Comment: There has to be an existing canvas with the id "canvas" in the html markup for this to work. This looks like its maybe copy pasta code you got from somewhere, so if you want it to work you will have to add a canvas element into your page, or change your code to create an insert a new one, rather than trying to select an element which doesnt exist.

Comment: @Newtrat you have to create,set id,add to document.

Comment: @slackOverflow this is the only reason for canvas to be null.